# In Linux, how do I send packets of a certain size to an IP?

Tags: linux, unix, ip, tcp, packets

What commands can you run? (must be via the terminal)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the packet size in ping using "-s" flag:

```
-s packetsize
          Specifies the number of data bytes to be sent.  The default is 56, which  translates  into
          64 ICMP data bytes when combined with the 8 bytes of ICMP header data.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ping -s nnnn a.b.c.d
```

sends packets of size nnnn+8 bytes (including header data) to address a.b.c.d, according to the manpage.

Answer (score -3):

`[root@example ~]# ping -s install.log 192.168.68.107`
`PING 192.168.68.107 (192.168.68.107) 0(28) bytes of data.`
`8 bytes from 192.168.68.107: icmp_req=1 ttl=64`
`8 bytes from 192.168.68.107: icmp_req=2 ttl=64`
`8 bytes from 192.168.68.107: icmp_req=3 ttl=64`

try like this :)

Comment: -1, the `-s` argument takes packet size as an integer, not a file name.